# Java / TomCat BaseDao NoInitialContextException

Tags: java, tomcat, dao

For school they're making us connect to a postgresDB trough plain old dao's and tomcat. However the given code ain't working and I've been stuck here for quite a bit now.

So here goes.

The connectiondao given:

```
package nl.hu.v1wac.firstapp.persistence;

import java.sql.Connection;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class BaseDao {
  protected final Connection getConnection() {
    Connection result = null;

    try {
      InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
      DataSource ds = (DataSource)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/PostgresDS");

      result = ds.getConnection();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

We had to write the server specifics into an context.xml file, and import the jar driver into the lib folder of tomcat (so far so good). The context.xml is in the src/main/webapp/META-INF directory

The context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/PostgresDS"
url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/worlddb"
driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
username="postgres"
password="secret" />
</Context>
```

After setting up my Dao's, I try to fire them up in a main and get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

which is said caused by:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/PostgresDS");
```

Would anyone be able to help, as according the slides / manual this should be all to it :/

Thanks in advance!

p.s. we're using tomcat 8.5 and Eclipse Jee Neon

Edited Main class

```
package nl.hu.v1wac.firstapp.persistence;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Pattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CountryDao cdao = new CountryDaoPostgreSQL();
        try {
            cdao.findALl();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly shouldn't be getting that.

You're running this code within Tomcat proper? Not outside? The complaint is that the InitialContext doesn't have the underlying "plumbing" to do the lookup. Normally this is all managed by the environment that you're running in, unless you're running it "stand alone" in a Java SE app, you should never see this.

Comment: I get this error after running my main in Eclipse Jee Neon, which uses the Dao to run a specific dao.method. This dao implements the dao interface and basedao superclass. 

(I've added the main to the code above)

Comment: You need to get your code in to a Servlet and deploy it in to Tomcat. There's a fundamental step that you're missing, but you'll need to clarify all that with your class.